# Extract text from cell in Excel between two different characters

Tags: excel, text, excel-formula

I am trying to pull the following

`Z:\Family\Animal\Food\Type\[Food_Type.xlsm]`

from the this formula:

`=INDEX('Z:\Family\Animal\Food\Type\[Food_Type.xlsm]Berries'!$10:$10,MATCH(E4,'Z:\Family\Animal\Food\Type\[Food_Type.xlsm]Berries'!$12:$12,0))`

I thought I would be able to use the following formula to select everything between the `'` and the `]` but I keep getting an error and I'm not sure why its not working.

```
=MID(LEFT(A1,FIND("]",A1)-1),FIND("'",A1)+1,LEN(A1))
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your formula `MID(...` works on the *result* of the other formula (`=INDEX('Z:...`) you need to use [FORMULATEXT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FORMULATEXT-function-0A786771-54FD-4AE2-96EE-09CDA35439C8)

Comment: Thanks!!! I didn't realize that.  I updated the formual to the following and it is working as intended! `=MID(LEFT(FORMULATEXT(A1),FIND("]",FORMULATEXT(A1))-1),FIND("'",FORMULATEXT(A1))+1,LEN(FORMULATEXT(A1)))`